# Is there any way I could auto-fill the fields on this registration page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link to a registration page:
[Registration Page](https://www.website.ws/orderflow/index.dhtml?sponsor=gditraffic&src=DSP_66&last_page=DSP_66)

When I take users to the page, I'd like to save them a load of time, frustration and calories to burn, by filling in the fields automatically.

The whole form is ran in JavaScript and JQuery by the looks of things, but I have no idea where I would start to actually do something like this. I have the users details (to input into the fields) in a SQL db, so some PHP parsing to start off with.

Any ideas where I'd go from there?

SORRY,forgot to mention: I don't have any moderation access to the Reg page.

Comment: You have no control over the remote page, so unless it's got facilities to allow for auto-fill, there's not much you can do. You can try loading it up in an iframe and reachign into it that way from the framing page, but will most likely not be able to get that to work.

Comment: Probably not something you can host or link to.  You could write a browser plugin, or some JavaScript to be manually run on a JavaScript console by each user.

Comment: Nav, Can you clarify if you have control over the machines the users are using? As David says, automation with a browser plugin would be what i'd do too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I am seeing that you are able to fill in is the First and Last name.

I was able to do so by putting it in the url string.

https://www.website.ws/orderflow/index.dhtml?sponsor=gditraffic&src=DSP_66&last_page=DSP_66&firstname=John&lastname=Smith

Comment: I did attempt salutation and username, but they did not work. I don't think filling in password was proper and did not attempt to do so.